# No confirmation order email or any other email on magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I am using Magento community edition 1.9 and installed it to smarterasp.net. Whenever I try purchasing something and complete the process, I receive no email order notification. Nothing at all. Even when I try to invoice it, there is no invoice email. By the way, I already tried the fix available on the Internet, nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried to write a simple mail function in magento root and check if that is working.

Answer (score 1):

Please check email queue to better troubleshoot email issue. 
As all Magento e-mails (including order confirmation and transactional) are queued and sent according to your configured cron schedule.

Comment: Please do not include your signature in your posts - you can leave them in your profile if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Try first on localhost and install extension for mails like:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

If you need help installing, please, tell.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i want to know what is causing the issue?